# Pymol from Python, no background

Tags: python, background, pymol

I run script from python to pymol, everything is fine, until this line occurs:

```
        cmd.set('ray_opaque_background', 0)
```

I have function to save ready structures, everything is ok, no errors occurs, but background is not transparent, it's still black. Could someone tell me, what is wrong with this line?

Comment: Do you want to have a white background while working on a file in PyMol? Or do you want to have an opaque background for an imaged created from the current frame?

Comment: the thing is I can make white background simply by using comend:
cmd.bg_color('white')
but it gets tricky with "transparent"/absence of background

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with that line.

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve.
Do you have a command to save an image of the current frame of your structure?
If not, try adding the following lines which should produce a 600x600 pixels image image_name.png with an opaque background.

```
cmd.set('ray_opaque_background', 0)
cmd.ray(600,600)
cmd.png("image_name.png")
```

Comment: still it's not working, it returns pictures with black background, I guess it's hopeless